# How to use "marker" in R-studio

Tags: rstudio

I found that by using mouse click, we can create a red dot as a "marker" in R-studio. This is very nice. But how to simply go to this line with a marker?

I use SAS also. In SAS, it is like pressing Ctrl+F2 to create a marker, and press F2 to go to the next marker.

Anyone use this before? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That isn't a marker but rather a breakpoint. When you run a script with a breakpoint, execution will stop there. Unfortunately there isn't currently a way to jump to breakpoints.

You can get similar behavior by inserting sections: use Code -> Insert Section to add a section, then Code -> Jump To to jump to any section quickly (there are hotkeys for these as well).

Comment: I see. I even use a break point as a marker. LOL. Thanks, I will do a search on "How to insert section in R-studio".

Comment: Shortcut to insert section `CTRL+SHIFT+R`.

Comment: Shortcut to jump to section `ALT+SHIFT+J`.